# MVC Returning to a view and showing the partial view that was there

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Alright, so currently I am working with MVC 4 to make a web app.  I am still new to MVC and have hit road blocks and got past them, but I am having trouble finding an answer for my current problem.

My main view, Course, has several partial views, AllCourses and CurrentCourses, that the user can switch between with a couple links.  It just displays a list of courses from a database mainly, the links change which will display based on the date.  The Course view also has a button that takes them to an entirely new view, Details, which displays the content for the course.  In the Details view there is a return link that takes me back to the previous view, Course.

What I need the return link to do is to take them to the previous view, but also display the partial view that was showing when they clicked to view the course details, aka if they were on the AllCourses partial view when they return I want that partial view to show and same if they were on the CurrentCourses.

EDIT::

My Partial views in the main view is handled by:

```
<ul id="view-options">
    <li><a href="javascript:getAll();">View All </a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:getCurrent();">View Current</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getAll() {
        $("#result").load("@Url.Action("AllCourses", "Course")");
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCurrent() {
        $("#result").load("@Url.Action("CurrentCourses", "Course")");
    }
</script>

<div id="result">
.
.
</div>
```

Just two text links to switch between views.

And my link to the details view is:

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="View Course" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.CourseID })'" />
```

The call back to the main view is similar to the above.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If the partial view was rendered in the previous page using@Html.Partial("_somepartialview")  it should automatically should when the view is loaded ( hoping your link uses @Html.ActionLink(....)

Comment: You need pass some value indicating the state of the original view to the details view, which in turn can be added as a route parameter to the return link.

Comment: @StephenMuecke So I can see how I would pass a parameter in general, but how would I pass the state of the partial view forward and then back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I need to add paging to the view.  So I ended up just adding a filter to the page and went with PagedList.Mvc and got rid of the partial views.